# Create object with part of interface. Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem, please help.

We have two interfaces:

```
interface IUserEntity {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}

interface IUserEntityMethods {
    GetFullName(): string;
}
```

I would like to create an object that will have type `IUserEntityMethods`, but within the method `GetFullName` through `this` in Webstorm (for example) dropped autocomplete with the ability to use the properties of the interface `IUserEntity`.

What I want to get in the end:

```
var userEntityMethods: IUserEntityMethods = {
    GetFullName: function() {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; // We have no errors at this line.
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you divided the methods from the properties into two interfaces, but basically all you need to do is to have one extend the other, like so:

```
interface IUserEntity {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}

interface IUserEntityMethods extends IUserEntity {
    GetFullName(): string;
}
```

Then instances of `IUserEntityMethods` should have the methods and the properties.
But then you'll need to have them in the concrete instance:

```
var userEntityMethods: IUserEntityMethods = {
    Id: A_NUMBER,
    FirstName: A_STRING,
    LastName: A_STRING,
    GetFullName: function() {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class that implements both interfaces:

```
class UserEntity implements IUserEntity, IUserEntityMethods {
    public Id: number;
    public FirstName: string;
    public LastName: string;

    public GetFullName(): string {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const userEntity: UserEntity = new UserEntity();
userEntity.Id = 1;
userEntity.FirstName = "John";
userEntity.LastName = "Doe";
console.log(userEntity.GetFullName());
```